# C#, Unity, need help making a dictionary of <int, class>

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I tried to look a bit about dictionaries and it should work,

any idea why it doesn't?

first I make a class with private properties:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class level
{
    private string levelTitle;
    private int moneyValue;

    public string LevelTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return levelTitle;
        }

        set
        {
            levelTitle = value;
        }
    }

    public int MoneyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return moneyValue;
        }

        set
        {
            moneyValue = value;
        }
    }

    public level(string levelTitle, int moneyValue)
    {
        this.LevelTitle = levelTitle;
        this.moneyValue = moneyValue;
    }
}
```

btw, in the class constructor, should I assign the private properties themself or through their get set methods?

anyway, then on another script, I make a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<int, level> levels = new Dictionary<int, level>()
{
    {0, new level{"Green Field Forever", 1}},
    {1, new level{"Golden Vally", 2}}
};
```

which gives me a bunch of error including :

the level type argument doesn't take 0 arguments

Comment: To answer the sub-question of whether you should use the Properties or the variables to assign values, it really doesn't matter from a functionality stand point (as long as your Getter and Setter do nothing with the value other than set it), although it might be better to standardize what you do (i.e. always Property or always Variable)

Answer (score 2):

use parentheses instead of curly braces, because you want to pass values to the constructor. curly braces is used for object-initializers.

```
new level("Green Field Forever", 1)
```

Another way of doing this is to use object initializer with **property names** that you want to set:

```
new level{ LevelTitle = "Green Field Forever", MoneyValue = 1}
```

Note: As @ken2k mentioned in comments you need a parameterless constructor to use object initializers. since you have added a constructor to your class that takes some parameters, the default constructor will be ignored. you need to add that manually like this:

```
public level() { }
```

Comment: There is no parameterless constructor in the OP's example, so object initializer syntax won't be accepted.

Comment: @ken2k you are right, that's a good point. I have uptated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
new level{"Golden Vally", 2}}
```

should be

```
new level("Golden Vally", 2) }
```

Also have a look to C# feature called [auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) that was introduced in the version 3.0 of the language that came with .Net 3.5 (so it's available in any IDE that supports this version of the language).

And generally speaking you should **not** set a value for the backing field associated with your property.

Comment: can I use auto implemented properties with monodevelop? (I think it's .NET 3.5)

Comment: @SethKeno Sure you can, it's a standard C# feature

Comment: @ken2k Should be noted that it's not a C# programming language feature, but a C# compiler feature. As such it's not actually implemented in VS2005 and earlier

Comment: @Nunners It **is** a C# language feature. Introduced with the version 3.0 of the language. So while it's true there is a link between the .Net version you can target and the IDE you can use, it really comes with the language itself.

Comment: @ken2k That's a fair point, just wanted to point out that it can't be used in some older IDEs, which some people (like me) have the unfortunate pleasure to work with...

Comment: @Nunners That was a good point, so I updated the answer with more details